# Prepending Items to Scala Set

Tags: scala, scala-collections

In Scala I can prepend items to a `List` via:

```
scala> 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil
res16: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

What's the equivalent `::` operator for a Scala `Set`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `+`. It's not called "prepend", but "add". The reason is that `Set` doesn't guarantee an ordering for the inserted elements.

```
scala> val s = Set(1, 2, 3)
s: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)

scala> s + 3
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)

scala> s + 4
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> s + 4 + 5
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: "prepend" e.g. with `Set(0) ++ Set(1,2,3)`
so the sourcecode reads nicer, even it is not ordered internally

Comment: @HartmutPfarr one reason I wouldn't do that (but it's still just a hypothesis), is that the 2nd argument of `++` might be huge and you end up recreating it anew because all the elements of the 2nd set are added to the 1st one.